# calling function batch file

Tags: batch-file

I call in my batch file to a function.after the function finish the flow continu and then when I goto the tag END in the end of the batch file it return to the space that I call to the function aa and print zi.

```
 :b  
 call :aa 1
 echo zi
 call :rr
 **goto end**



:aa
if...(
goto b)else(
goto end

:end
echo finish
```

Comment: Your question really doesn't make any sense, have you read it yourself? Please re word so we can help you, at the moment I don't know what your question is.

Answer (score 2):

This question doesn't make much sense. For a start I struggle even understanding what you mean, but looking at the code there are a few things that are obvious:

1. Labels are written as `:label`, not `label:`. So `b:` just changes the drive, `aa:` and `end:` are just invalid syntax.
2. Calling a subroutine will cause all “end of batch file” conditions to mean “return from subroutine” instead. This includes end of file, `goto :eof` and `exit /b`. Usually subroutines end with `goto :eof` and you also need to use something similar *above* all subroutines to avoid running into them after your regular program flow.
3. `if %1>2` probably just means “Syntax error, but redirecting the standard output stream to the standard error stream”. At least here it just says `1> was unexpected at this time.`. Which is about expected. If you want to say “If *foo* then *bar* else *baz*” then use the following:

   ```
   if foo (
     bar
   ) else (
     baz
   )
   ```

   And you cannot compare things with `>` or `<` in batch files. You have to use `GTR` or `LSS`:

   ```
   if %1 GTR 1 goto b else goto end
   ```

Comment: I dont understand wht after the bold line it doto the end print finish and then return and print zi and comtinu from there